# Count the number of element repeats at various distances

Tags: function-construction, map, counting

I have a function of `x`:

```
f[x_] := Abs[Extract[list, x + n] - Extract[list, x]]
```

I then apply this:

```
g = Length[Cases[Map[f, Table[i, {i, Length[list] - n}]], 0]]
```

This counts the number of occurences when two letters are the same at a distance of `n` in the list.

However, I wish to be able to alter the value of `n`, and map the values of `g` as `n` takes the value of `1,2,3,..` etc. Is there a way to do this? I simply want *Mathematica* to let `n` be `1`, apply `g`, let `n` be `2`, apply `g`... etc and then to map the results?

Any replies are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
comp[a_, b___, c_] := a == c
k[list_, dist_] := Count[ListConvolve[SparseArray[{1 -> 1, # -> 1}, #]&[dist+1], list, {-1, 1}, 0, 
                                      Times, comp], 
                        True]

list = {d, a, e, a, e, b, e, b, c, d, d};
k[list, #] & /@ Range[Length[list] - 1]

(* {1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would this would achieve what you described (I haven't been using MMA as much as I would like so my answer might be clumsy):

```
Clear[countSameLetters]
countSameLetters[list_List, distance_Integer] :=
 Position[
   Flatten@Differences@Position[list, #] & /@ 
    CharacterRange["a", "z"], distance] // Length
```

To display each distance with its corresponding count and repeated letters:

```
Clear[countAndDisplaySameLetters]
countAndDisplaySameLetters[list_List, distance_Integer] :=
 Module[{distancePerLetter, aToZ, letterPositions},
  aToZ = CharacterRange["a", "z"];
  letterPositions = 
   First /@ 
    Position[Differences@Flatten@Position[list, #] & /@ aToZ, 
     distance];
  {distance, Length[letterPositions], 
   Part[aToZ, DeleteDuplicates@letterPositions]}
  ]
```

Testing:

```
randomChar = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
countSameLetters[randomChar, 5]
(* 2 *)

countAndDisplaySameLetters[randomChar, 5]
(* {5, 2, {"e", "i"}} *)

countAndDisplaySameLetters[randomChar, #] & /@ Range[1, 10] // 
 TableForm[#, 
   TableHeadings -> {None, {"Distance", "Count", "Letters"}}, 
   TableSpacing -> {5, 2}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]